# C# ComboBox Selected Text To Multiple Strings

Tags: string, combobox

I have a combobox that has the entries of a full name, eg: John Smith, Mark Tall, etc.

I have written the following:

```
string FullName = StudentSelectStudentComboBox.Text;
```

This gets "John Smith" as the string 'FullName'. Is it possible to break down 'FullName' string into 2 strings; FirstName and LastName?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `string.split`

```
string str = "John Adams";
string[] names=   str.Split(' ');    //names[0]="John"   names[1]="Adams"
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer is similar to [the one abov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1653194/3834)e but with a twist:
If you want to get fancy you can try:

///////////////

//Names[0] = first name, Name[1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1653194/3834) = last name

```
string[] Names = StudentSelectStudentComboBox.Text.Split(' ');
```

////////